# pass custom variable/parameter from email template to phtml file

Tags: orders, email-templates

I am stuck in my custom code.

I want to pass a custom variable from email template to pthml file.

Edit file

> app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

in this function :

```
public function sendNewOrderEmail()
  {

--- default code start ----
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $this,
                'test'        => 'XXXXX',
                'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
            )
        );
--- default code end ----
}
```

and then I put this code in New Order email template:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order  test=$test}}
```

template file located here :

> app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html

and I am trying to get test variable Here:

> app/design/frontend/default/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

like this: `$test = $this->getItem()->getTest()`

but get success. Please let me know where am I wrong? or what to do need to access this variable in phtml file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the "test variable" is it a customer attribute, product attribute, a block of test, etc?

Comment: it's a merchant emails array

Answer (score 9):

When passing a variable this way:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order  test=$test}}
```

You make it available in the `email/order/items.phtml` template only.
You are able to get it there with:  `$this->getTest()` or `$this->getData('test')`.
To pass it further to the `email/order/items/order/default.phtml` edit the `items.phtml` file and add this

```
$item->setTest($this->getTest());
```

before calling

```
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
```

To make it shorter, replace:

```
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item->setTest($this->getTest())) ?>
```

Comment: You save my time.... Genius :)