# Template vars/placeholders

Tags: template, email-templates, variables, template-directive, placeholder

Relatively new to Magento and seeing a lot of this lately in (email) templates:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
{{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}} 
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}} 
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}} 
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='sales/custom_logic.phtml'}}
```

For example: **{{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}**

Is order a model instance and can you just call every available function as you would in plain PHP code?

I see functions getting called, variables passed around with $, ... But I am missing a **global overview / documentation of exactly what is available and what can/should be used where**.

Where can I find a good overview of all this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is order a model instance and can you just call every available function as you would in plain PHP code? -> **Yes**

Inside template '$order' means **Mage_Sales_Model_Order**, So you can use any function that exist in this class. If missing then add missing function for this class.

**Updated**

[Magento Predefined Variables 1](https://dbachmann.github.io/m1-userguide/cms/variables-predefined.html)
[Magento Predefined Variables 2](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/cms/variables-predefined.html)

Check[here](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates)

[another](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/25/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates/)

[another](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12379/pass-custom-variable-parameter-from-email-template-to-phtml-file)

Comment: Tnx, Sohei! And you're suppose to use them only in email templates and in CMS/Pages/Blocks, right? Still looking for a complete overview of all available tags, though...

Comment: I updated answer